# Where should I place block icons and CSS in magento extension

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

My magento extension adds a new block (like the poll block for example) to the sidebar.
I am using the same html structure as that used by the poll block to make the block look like its part of the system.

i.e.

```
<div class="block block-myblock">
   <div class="block-title">
      <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('block title') ?></span></strong>
   </div>...
```

I know that the icons on the poll block apear because of a CSS rule:

```
.block-poll .block-title strong { background-image:url(../images/i_block-poll.gif); }
```

that is returned from: `/skin/frontend/base/default/css/widgets.css`

and I also know that the image itself is stored at:
`skin/frontend/default/default/images/`

I have two Questions:

1. What would be the appropriate way to add my own require CSS rule to show the icon near my block ? 
   i.e. does `.block-myblock .block-title strong { background-image:url(../images/i_block-myblock.gif); }` go directly into some file ? and which file or is it added by the code of the block using some call like addCSS or something similar ?
2. What would be the appropriate path for me to store the `i_block-myblock.gif` image ?

please remember that this is all in the context of an extension,  not local modifications to my own store.

Comment: also, if someone with a reputation of 1500 can add a magento-extansions tag that would be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very good question and +1 for keeping the Magento wording in your CSS !
What I personnally do in order not to confuse developpers that may use my module is that I create a skin subfolder dedicated to the module. This way, it will be whether easy to find and cut/paste its css rules and images in the right theme folder whether running correctly for non experimented users.

**1- Create the folder and files architecture**

Like :

- /skin/frontend/default/default/[your_module_name]/css/styles.css
- /skin/frontend/default/default/[your_module_name]/images/ (containing all your module's images)

**2- Edit your /skin/frontend/default/default/[your_module_name]/css/styles.css**

...as usual but containing only CSS classes related to your module, ie :

```
.block-myblock .block-title strong { background-image:url(../images/i_block-myblock.gif); }
```

**3- Call the CSS file from the layout XML of your module**

Open, let's say /app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/[your_module_name].xml
and add the following lines after the first  opening node like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<!-- Code to add -->
 <default>
  <reference name="head">
   <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>[your_module_name]/css/styles.css</name><params/></action>
  </reference>
 </default>
<!-- [end] -->
.
.
.
</layout>
```

This should work while being respectful of Magento standards, not polluting existing themes and giving no headaches to developpers who wish to fully merge your skin with theirs.

Comment: If I understand properly, I can do the CSS injection from the actual code of my block so that if my block is not on the page the CSS will not be there either. Do you know what method of my block would be most suitable for this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand well your comment :) The injection / call to your CSS files is done via the theme layout XML file of your module. It must not be done neither using the phtml neither the php Block relative to this phtml. There is no problem with the CSS being here (because it's called in the head via the XML) while there is no HTML item using it on the currently-displayed page.

Comment: In other words, [this](http://store.redstage.com/blog/2012/07/24/how-to-properly-include-custom-css-and-js-files-in-magento)

Comment: Benubird's link is not consistent in regards to the original question. The original question is related to *custom module* design (and layout updates) whereas Benubird's link deals with project theme updates (using local.xml). local.xml is meant to overload the original layout xml files that may be present with a packaged module.